# find value show zero if not exist SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data like:

```
SerivceID   Service_Name            Serivce_Charges     FK_VendorID FK_ExpertID FK_CustomerID   BookingDate TimeSlot    current_Job GettingJobDate
4           Furniture & Home Decor  200                 1                2      1               08-11-2017  3              1         2018-02-04 13:57:49.733
```

in an row. Now i want to get count which query is:

```
select A_Services.Service_Name as [Service Name],count(Service_Name) as [Total Serve] 
from A_Services where FK_ExpertID = 2 group by Service_Name order by [Service Name]
```

it shows data:

```
Service Name            Total Serve
Furniture & Home Decor  1
```

i want to get data as :

```
Service Name            Total Serve
Furniture & Home Decor  1
Car Towing              0
```

Comment: Fix your formatting.  I was unable to do so when I tried to edit the question.

Comment: So if car towing is not part of your table, you would still like to show it? Then what is the base table containing all names?

Answer (score 1):

**Impossible with your current data.**

The "Car Towing" should come from somewhere, the computer doesn't have preseted service names. How can it know if it ends with "Towing" or "Throwing" or "Tow"?

You need to specify somewhere.

(You can select what you have, but can't show data you don't have)

---

## Solution:

Can the same service be connected to different vendors OR experts OR customers?

If yes, I suggest you to create a Service Type category. (Id, Name)

```
Id   Name
1    Furniture & Home Decor 
2    Car Towing          
3    Car Painting
4    Etc...

/*Name should be Unique*/
```

Then instead of using **Service_Name**, you could use a **ServiceType_FK**

With that data, you can query:

```
SELECT ST.Name AS [Service Name], COUNT(S.ServiceType_FK) AS [Total Serve] 
FROM ServiceType ST
LEFT JOIN A_Services S
ON S.ServiceType_FK = ST.Id
--WHERE S.FK_ExpertID = 2
GROUP BY ST.Name
```

Which returns what you want.